# How to sort a Scala List[Map[String, Any]] by an arbitrary number of keys in the Map?

Tags: scala

I have a `List[Map[String, Any]]` that represents the results of a query.

The keys of a map instance (or row) are the column names.

Each query is different and its result may contain a different set of columns, compared to any other query. Queries cannot be predicted in advance, hence I cannot use case classes to represent a result row.

Within the results for a given query, all columns appear in every row.

The values are largely `Int`, `Double` and `String` types.

I need to be able to sort the results by multiple columns, in both ascending and descending order.

For example, in pseudocode / SQL:

`ORDER BY column1 ASC, column2 DESC, column3 ASC`

I have three distinct problems:

1. Sort by a single column where its type (in the map, as opposed its underlying type) is `Any`
2. Sort by either direction
3. Chain multiple sort instructions together

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

I can do part 1. and part 2. by writing a custom Ordering[Any]. I don't yet know how to chain the sorts together.

Comment: Regarding the 3rd point, you could just keep the sorts in some collection (since they are objects in Scala), say a `List` and then apply them one by one to the data.

Comment: Since `sorted` takes an `Ordering[Any]`, and returns a new list, why can't you just sort them in reverse order of precedence? That is, if you want to sort by `col1` and then `col2`, apply `sorted` to `col2`, then apply `sorted` for `col1` to the result of the first sort?

Comment: Nathaniel - can you give a quick scala code snippet? `sorted` doesn't take any arguments, so how would I apply it for a given column?